# /bin/sh: clang++: command not found

Tags: debian, command-line, software-installation

I use Debian 5. I was building GN. I followed the instruction provided [here](https://gn.googlesource.com/gn/).
 I was executing these commands:

```
git clone https://gn.googlesource.com/gn
cd gn
python build/gen.py
ninja -C out
```

While executing `ninja -C out/` I receive this message:

```
ninja: Entering directory `out/'   
[1/238] CXX tools/gn/input_file.o  
FAILED: tools/gn/input_file.o   
clang++ -MMD -MF tools/gn/input_file.o.d  -I/home/us/WebRTCBuild/gn -I/home/us/WebRTCBuild/gn/out -DNDEBUG -O3 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -pthread -pipe -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fdiagnostics-color -std=c++14 -Wno-c++11-narrowing -c /home/us/WebRTCBuild/gn/tools/gn/input_file.cc -o tools/gn/input_file.o    
/bin/sh: clang++: command not found
[2/238] CXX base/callback_internal.o     
FAILED: base/callback_internal.o    
clang++ -MMD -MF base/callback_internal.o.d  -I/home/us/WebRTCBuild/gn -I/home/us/WebRTCBuild/gn/out -DNDEBUG -O3 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -pthread -pipe -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fdiagnostics-color -std=c++14 -Wno-c++11-narrowing -c /home/us/WebRTCBuild/gn/base/callback_internal.cc -o  
base/callback_internal.o       
/bin/sh: clang++: command not found        
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

As far as I understand problem shown in this message:

> /bin/sh: clang++: command not found

I already installed llvm. But it didn't work. 
I also read that it may be caused by absence of g++. But g++ installed.

Result of executing `echo $PATH`:

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/gcc49/bin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem by avoiding clang compiler. I noticed that in `build/gen.py` there is option that gives me possibility to set compiler. By default it's clang. So in `build/gen.py` I changed this part that is below.

`def WriteGNNinja(path, platform, host, options):
  if platform.is_msvc():
    cc = os.environ.get('CC', 'cl.exe')
    cxx = os.environ.get('CXX', 'cl.exe')
    ld = os.environ.get('LD', 'link.exe')
    ar = os.environ.get('AR', 'lib.exe')
  elif platform.is_aix():
    cc = os.environ.get('CC', 'gcc')
    cxx = os.environ.get('CXX', 'g++')
    ld = os.environ.get('LD', 'g++')
    ar = os.environ.get('AR', 'ar -X64')
  else:
    cc = os.environ.get('CC', 'clang')
    cxx = os.environ.get('CXX', 'clang++')
    ld = cxx
    ar = os.environ.get('AR', 'ar')`

I Changed these lines:

`cc = os.environ.get('CC', 'clang')
    cxx = os.environ.get('CXX', 'clang++')
    ld = cxx
    ar = os.environ.get('AR', 'ar')`

to this:

`cc = os.environ.get('CC', 'gcc')
    cxx = os.environ.get('CXX', 'gcc')
    ld = cxx
    ar = os.environ.get('AR', 'gcc')`

Now I receive errors during executing `ninja -C out` but they connected to compiling of code. Problem of **/bin/sh: clang++: command not found** solved

Answer (score 2):

While [the Lenny package archive](https://historical.packages.debian.org/lenny/) is not working for me right now, the file **/usr/bin/clang++** is [provided by](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/clang/filelist) the **clang** package on Debian 8 Jessie. The **llvm** package does not depend on the **clang** package so **clang** may not be installed. Try installing it with  `sudo apt install clang`. If that does not work could you run `echo $PATH` and post the results?

Comment: `sudo apt install clang` and `sudo apt-get install clang` doesn't work for me. Result of `echo $PATH` I posted in question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by amending the path like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/clang-11:/usr/bin/clang++-11
```

You would change 11 to whichever version you're using. This allows it to find the command in the bin. In most cases with a sudo apt-get install, it seems to do this automatically, but not always.